# How to assign the dynamic link for "like button" of google+ and twitter

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter, google-plus

I have a website that has an iframe in it that contains dynamic content (one time it is this link and other time it is that link etc..) . **outside** the iframe (in the regular site) I have 3 social buttons: Facebook Twitter & Google+.

**I want the user to click on the social-buttons outside the iframe - but to like the iframe itselft ***

To connect the iframe link to facebook is easy because I have data-href and I can put there the iframe's link:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.theIframeLinkIwant.com/" .../>
```

**However how do I do it for twitter & Google+ - they don't have that sort of field:**

```
<g:plusone size="medium" annotation="inline" width="120" class="googlePlus"></g:plusone>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>
```

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 1):

For the twitter button read [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.yourwebsite.com">Tweet</a>
```

For google plus read [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/)

```
<g:plusone annotation="inline" href="http://www.yourwebsite.com"></g:plusone>
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue for google+ was in the advance option:

just needed to add the href:

```
<g:plusone annotation="inline" href="http://www.whatever.com"></g:plusone>
```